# Is it possible to tls login (authentication) for AWS Document DB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas, atlas

Is TLS login (Authentication) available for AWS Document DB? In Atlas MongoDB we are able to authenticate with TLS key file. But unable to login AWS document DB.